# Analyze only one partition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, maintenance

I have a `metrics` table partitioned by year and month (`metrics_y2023m01`, `metrics_y2023m02`, etc). The `analyze metrics` command updates the statistics of the table and each partition individually, but the vast majority of modifications occur in the partition of the current month, so I had thought about spacing out the execution of the analysis of the entire table in time and schedule another daily analyze of the busiest partition.

- Does it make sense to analyze a single partition without updating the statistics of the parent table?
- Can I analyze a single partition and the parent table without having to analyze the other partitions?
- What weight do the statistics of the parent table have with respect to the statistics of the partitions in the query planner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to `ANALYZE` a single partition. However, you shouldn't do it manually: adjust `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` and `autovacuum_analyze_threshold` for that table so that autovacuum runs the `ANALYZE` automatically at the proper intervals.

If you `ANALYZE` the partitioned table, all partitions will be analyzed. There is no way to avoid that. It is actually a good thing to schedule such an `ANALYZE` occasionally, because autovacuum does not treat partitioned tables, but the statistics on the partitioned table still can be important for query planning. It depends on the statement whether the statistics for the partitioned table or the statistics for the partition are more important. Both should be in good shape.

Comment: Thanks. I had mistakenly assumed that the autovacuum daemon also ignored partitions and not just the partitioned table.